# Laravel 5.2 model "Unexpected data found"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my project I have an array and the object from the model, these two should be compared.

The model has id, name and surname, and the same fields are contained in the array. So, when I do

```
$user = User::find($data['id']);
```

So if I call

```
return array($user->id, $user->name, $user->surname);
```

I shall get

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 'John'
[2] => 'Doe'
```

And this part is working okay.

Meanwhile, the $data array is passing serialized form, so

```
return $data;
```

Will print out, for example

```
['id'] => ['1']
['name'] => ['John']
['surname'] => ['Smith']
```

And this part is also okay.

**And here is the place where problems start**.

I've got a piece of code that looks as follows:

```
$fields = ['name', 'surname'];
foreach($fields as $field) {
    if($user->{$field} != $data[$field])
        $user->update([$field => $data[$field]]);
}
```

**And at the moment where these two are compared, I get an error "Unexpected data found".**

I've tried returning all these fields and types, they are all existing strings. Also, if I replace any part of `if` statement with a static string, it will work. I've also tried additional converting to strings, like

```
if(gettext($user->{$field}) != gettext($data[$field]))
```

But it did not help.

I've also tried replacing model with direct connection to the database, but it did not work as well.

What am I doing wrong? The strangest part is that I have the exact same code in the other controller and it works fine there.

Comment: Can you write the whole exception?

Comment: It's just "Unexpected data found\nUnexpected data found"

Comment: Do you only have those 3 fields?

Comment: No, I have more, but does that matter if I take only those listed in the array?

Comment: So its just happening for `name` and `surname`? I made a quick search. And that kind of error only thrown when doing something with the date or time. So maybe check for time related fields.

Comment: why you are not updating complete row in user table.

Comment: Because there are a lot of fields most of which will remain the same, and updating them to the same value is kinda overkilling

Comment: but as you compare the value of each column it alse time taken you try like this $user[$field] != $data[$field];

Comment: "updating them to the same value is kinda overkilling" - No, it's overkill doing a work that laravel and the DB can do for you.